# <optgroup label='-------'></optgroup> gives xhtml validation error

Tags: html, css, optgroup

```
Error: End tag for 'optgroup' which is not finished. You have probably failed to 
include a required child element. Hence the parent element is "not finished",
 not complete.
```

I want to achieve something like this in select options.

```
USA
UK
--
Afghanistan
```

I want to put few important countries on top and then a non-selectable divider and then ordered list of remaining countries.

I put this divider using empty 'optgroup'. While it works perfectly in all browser, I get validation error.

**What could be other approaches to implement this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to what @ZippyV wrote, you can just use an `<option>` and make it be disabled:

```
<option disabled='disabled'>--</option>
```

That won't be selectable.  Also if it were me I'd use an m-dash and not two hyphens:

```
<option disabled='disabled'>&mdash;</option>
```

Comment: "semantically valid" -- what does that mean?  It'll validate because "disabled" is a valid XHTML (Strict, even) attribute for `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any code, but I bet you have something like:

```
<select>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>UK</option>
    <optgroup label="---"></optgroup>
    <option>Afghanistan</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

This is invalid because your optgroup contains no option elements. You need to use something like:

```
<select>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>UK</option>
    <optgroup label="---">
        <option>Afghanistan</option>
        <option>...</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: This offsets optgroup options.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an optgroup for this.
Just put this `<option val="-">--</option>` in your code

Comment: @SLaks if an option is disabled, it's not selectable. Now, I don't know whether the "disabled" attribute is OK in the relevant XHTML DTD.